# How to prepare my data for spaghetti plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I would like to create a spaghetti plot [similar to this one here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/10/my-commonly-done-ggplot2-graphs/)

[image: 1].

Unfortunately my data looks like this

[image: 2].
I have 11 columns that have NA's, so I remove them with
`neuron1 <- drop_na(neuron)`

Then I have a datatable with 13 columns and 169 rows. My goal is to display the expression of each gene across these 169 rows. Basically I would only need the "area" on the x-axis and on the y-axis the 11 genes. I am able to plot the data, but only when selecting the genes specifically e.g with this code:

```
ggplot(neuron1, aes(area)) + 
geom_line(aes(y=MAP2, group=1)) +
geom_line(aes(y=REEP1, group=1, color="red"))
```

It would be okay to repeat this 11 times but I have some datasets with more genes so it would really be nice to be able to group them properly and then run a short code.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. This is a line plot, not a spaghetti plot. You don't need to remove your NA, ggplot2 will do this for you. Bring the data into long format.

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/q/3777174/7941188

Comment: Dear Tjebo, thank you very much for editing and answering! I'm pretty new to R so some basic functions still seem hard to me.. I saw that I can bring my datatable to a long format by the melt() or gather() function, but somehow I don't get the datatable that I would need. Could you tell me how I specifiy the different genes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To long for comment. Lacking your data, this code may be a bit of a shot into the dark.
Try something like this:

```
library (tidyverse)

yourdata %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(-area, -region), names_to = "key", values_to = "value") %>%

ggplot(aes(area, value) +
  geom_line(aes(group = key))
```

Not sure how this will work with your area as an x, because it's a categorical variable (therefore not sure if `geom_line` is the right choice for visualisation)

Comment: Thank you very much tjebo! The code solved my problem :)