# How to draw multiple lines with slightly different x-axis values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a ggplot2 with 2 lines. The x,y values for the 2 lines are different. I have done this with regular line plot as

```
plot(d$ball,d$total,col="blue",type="l",lwd=2,xlab="Overs",ylab='Runs',
     main="Worm chart of match")
lines(d1$ball,d1$total,type="l",col="red",lwd=2)
teams <-c(t1,t2)
legend(x="topleft",legend=teams,
       col=c("blue","red"),bty="n",cex=0.8,lty=1,lwd=2)
```

Most of the ggplot2 examples I found assume that x values(usually date) are same with different y values.
How can I do this?

```
Test data
---------
x   k   y
3.1 1   15
3.2 0   15
3.3 0   15
3.4 0   15
3.5 1   16
3.6 0   16
3.7 1   17
3.8 4   21
4.1 4   21

 x1 m   y1
2.6 4   15
3.1 0   15
3.2 1   16
3.3 0   16
3.4 4   20
3.5 0   20
3.6 4   24
3.7 0   24
4.1 0   24
4.2 1   25
```

I need to plot x,y and x1,y1 in a single plot. The number rows will be different and the x,x1 value also may vary slightly

Comment: Hi, you could use a 3 column dataframe: one column with the line "name" (`line_name`), one colum with `x` values and one column with `y` values. Then use `aes()` let's say to color you lines. es: `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = line_name) + geom_line()`. If you want more help, please provide [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example

Comment: I think you will find some ideas here: [Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to merge yours dfs and reshape them on a tidy way, here is an idea:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = y, color = "1")) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x1, y = y1, color = "2")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Lines",
                     values = c("1" = "blue", "2" = "red"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 
                            4.1), k = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 4L), y = c(15L, 15L, 
                                                                                   15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                            -9L))
df2 <- structure(list(x1 = c(2.6, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 
                             4.1, 4.2), m = c(4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L), y1 = c(15L, 
                                                                                              15L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 -10L))
```

Comment: I tried merging them. It generates NAs. Need to see how to fix that. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might like the power of `tidyverse` packages (especially `dplyr` and `tidyr` in this case). Maybe have a look at https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html?q=join#mutating-joins and functions like `full_join()`, `pivot_longer()`