# ggplot, geom_line() for average number of occurences of each value of a string (categorical) variable in a dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot(). I have a dataset that has a variable called `"state_crossing"` which takes multiple string values - like *"baja california"*, *"sonora"* and *"tamaulipas"*. I saw some tricks on other threads on how to make multiple lines without needing to call a `geom_line()` for each variable (e.g., here [Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph)).

Then, I created a new variable `value = 1` for each observation, and I am using the following command:

```
plotting <- data.frame(
  year = rep(c("2001", "2002"), times=c(4,5)), 
  state_crossing = c("baja california", "baja california", "sonora", "tamaulipas", "sonora", "sonora", "tamaulipas", "tamaulipas", "baja california"), 
  value = rep(1, 9)
)

ggplot(plotting, aes(x=year, y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=state_crossing, group=state_crossing), stat = "summary", fun = "sum")
```

This is great, but it naturally plots the sum of occurrences, whereas I wanted the fraction of observations with that value of *state_crossing* within each value of `x = year`. The function "mean" doesn't work, as the mean is equal to 1 for the variable. Any idea of a `"fun"` that could give me the fraction?

E.g., on my reproducible example, I'd like "baja california" to show 2/3 in 2001, and then 0 in 2002; and "sonora" to show up as  "1/3" and then "1/2"

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I thought this was straightforward enough to not require one, sorry about that. Will add some data.

Comment: The example data provided doesn't produce a plot at all for me. I get the error "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do
you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

Comment: Sorry, try again. For some reason it needed a group argument. In the same data structure with more obs it wasn't giving this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to summarize data with ggplot can be a bit of a headache. It's great just for plotting data. So its easiest if you summarize your data into proportions first using something like `dplyr` and then you can easily plot the data.

```
library(dplyr)
plotting %>% 
  count(year, state_crossing) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(prop=n/sum(n)) %>% 
ggplot() +
  aes(x=year, y=prop, color=state_crossing, group=state_crossing) + 
  geom_line()
```