# How to use different color to represent several column of categorical binary data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that in a wide format represent lenders' characters for a banking credit system. I want to make a scatter plot using ggplot where colours represent the purpose of the credit. My table looks like this: where 1 means the purpose of the credit.

| lending_duration | lending_amount | Car | Furniture | TV/RADIO | House |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 month | 2000 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 16 months | 15600 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 month | 13094 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| etc... |  |  |  |  |  |

I tried:
`ggplot(Data, aes(x = DURATION, y = AMOUNT))+ geom_point(aes(color = c(Car, Furniture, 'TV/Ratio', House))+ scale_color_viridis_c()`
Not working out. Another question is how can I escape the / in the variable name, for example here TV/(OR)Radio, I try to use '' to escape the / in the variables but seems not working out.
Can someone help me here? Much appreciated!

Comment: You need to reshape your data from wide to long. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format. Then you map to color, see for ggplot2 specific answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for both questions. You can rename columns containing special characters by simply putting them in backticks:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

# your sample data in a df
df <- tibble(lending_duration = c("1 month", "16 month", "4 month"), 
       lending_amount = c(2000, 15600, 13094), 
       Car = c(0, 1 ,0), 
       furniture = c(1,0,0), 
       `TV/Radio` = c(0, 0, 0),
       House = c(0, 0, 1)) 

df %>%  rename(TV_or_Radio = `TV/Radio`) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Car, furniture, TV_or_Radio, House)) %>% 
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  # split string in lending_duration and use only first part converted to numeric, 
  # allows to plot durations in increasing order
  mutate(lending_duration = as.numeric(str_split(lending_duration, " ") %>% map_chr(., 1))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lending_duration, lending_amount, color = name)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  xlab("lending_duration in month")
```

[image]

Comment: Totally agree with you @tjebo, however, if I understood the question correctly, the problem was how to get rid of the ``TV/Radio`` column name.

Comment: yes, my apologies, I misudnerstood that! will delete my comment