# Why ggplot2 does not plot multiple lines

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am trying to plot three lines from my dataframe.
I read several posts regarding how to plot multiple lines into the same graph with ggplot2.
Stackoverflow suggested this one "[Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph)" and I tried it.

Here, is the database I am trying to plot:

```
test_df <- data.frame (samples = c("SRR7504771_sort", "SRR7504772_sort", "SRR7504773_sort", "SRR7504774_sort",
                                   "SRR7504775_sort", "SRR7504776_sort", "SRR7504777_sort", "SRR7504778_sort",
                                   "SRR7504779_sort", "SRR7504780_sort", "SRR7504781_sort", "SRR7504782_sort",
                                   "SRR7504783_sort", "SRR7504784_sort", "SRR7504785_sort", "SRR7504786_sort",
                                   "SRR7504787_sort", "SRR7504788_sort"),
                       MCBT_H37Rv_40_60 = c(57782763, 67674340, 54899455, 44669274, 56950512, 48855759, 52386587,
                                            49545209, 49227176, 45888933, 51202586, 63434537, 48509128, 57890225,
                                            50717205, 72839546, 60569151, 49096259),
                       MCBT_H37Rv_100_120 = c(57782639, 67674202, 54899363, 44669166, 56950405, 48855664, 52386480, 
                                              49545100, 49227101, 45888842, 51202499, 63434455, 48509002, 57890110, 
                                              50717155, 72839309, 60569035, 49096185),
                       MCBT_H37Rv_300_320 = c(57781333, 67672869, 54898438, 44668040, 56949390, 48854736, 52385075, 
                                              49544091, 49226094, 45887731, 51201465, 63433682, 48507580, 57888811, 
                                              50716314, 72837254, 60568018, 49095277)
)
```

And here is the code I used:

```
library("reshape2")

ggplot(data=test_data_long,
       aes(x=samples, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable)) +
       geom_line() + 
       theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=40, hjust=1))
```

I pass to ggplot the right stacked data as requested, but it does not work and my code still plot only 1 line.

[image]

The reason why I set "group" parameter in each aes was that I got an error if I run the command without setting groups.

```
> ggplot(data=test_data_long,
+        aes(x=samples, y=value, colour=variable)) +
+        geom_line() + 
+        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=40, hjust=1))
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
the group aesthetic?
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You did this correctly. However the data is so similar that the lines are on top of each other. You can see this by using `geom_jitter()` to wiggle the dots.

Comment: or add jitter directly to the lines `geom_line(position=position_jitter(w=.5, h=.5))+`

Comment: Yes, you are right!!!! I did not expect similar data and did not inspect them enough to catch that they overlapped in the lineplot. Thanks for your help M.Viking.