# Legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to add a legend to the attached plot.
The code I am using here here below. Unfortunately I cannot share the data. Would you please suggest how to modify the code so that the legend would actually show up?
Thanks
Michele

[image]

Here is the code that I am using

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(,show.legend = TRUE) +
  labs( x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
  ggtitle("Strike-Tried by Fishing Zones - FAO") +
  geom_sf(data = strike, pch = 16, color = "red",show.legend = TRUE) + 
  geom_sf(data = tried, pch =20, color = "navy", show.legend = TRUE) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + 
  geom_polygon(data = shp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "black", fill = NA) +
  scale_color_manual(values=colors, labels=c("Strike", "Tried"))
```

Comment: Please include a *minimal self-contained reproducible* example. You can generate some example data (see examples in the R help files and most questions on this site)

Comment: If you want to have a legend you have to map on aesthetics, i.e. try with e.g. `geom_sf(data = strike, aes(color = "strike"), pch = 16)`.

Comment: This question gets asked nearly every day on Stack Overflow, Michele. Instead of specifying the color directly inside `geom_sf` as `color = "red"` and `color = "navy"` ,  use `mapping = aes(color = "Strike")` and `mapping = aes(color = "Tried")`. Then your last line can be `scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "navy"))`

Comment: Here's one example of how this sort of question has been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3780353/6851825