# Smoothing breaks in lines on multi-line graph where data is missing (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm tracing tax trends over time, although where there are missing data points in the original dataset the lines appear broken. I'm looking for a way to smooth the lines so that the lines appear unbroken, even where there is missing data.

Is someone able to help? Thanks heaps :}

My code is:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=df_Sweden$CENTAXINCOMESH, color="Income Taxes"), group=1) +
  geom_line(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=df_Sweden$CENTAXPROPERTYSH, color="Property Taxes"), group=1) +
  geom_line(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=df_Sweden$CENTAXCUSTOMSSH, color="Customs and International Trade"), group=1) +
  geom_line(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=df_Sweden$CENTAXEXCISESH, color="Excise Taxes"), group=1) +
  geom_line(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=df_Sweden$CENTAXCONSSH, color="Consumption Taxes"), group=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100),
                     labels=scales::label_percent(scale=1),
                     expand = expansion(0,0)) +
   scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 30,
     limits = c(1890,2012), expand = c(0, 0)) + #yes shorted timeframe
  scale_color_manual(values=c("Income Taxes" = "#991f00", "Property Taxes" = "#ff3300", "Customs and International Trade" = "#00ffff", "Excise Taxes" = "#0099ff", "Consumption Taxes" = "#0000cc")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1)) +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("% of Government Revenue") +
  labs(color="Tax Type") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

[image: graph w broken lines]

I've roughly tried interpolation (though I don't think I understand it well enough for it to work). I came across something called spline (?) but couldn't download the package needed

Comment: or just use `geom_smooth()` if it's just visualization purpose.

Comment: Hi Phil – geom_smooth() isn't making a change. Is it meant to go somewhere specific? I've put it after all the geom_line() s

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was really obvious. Instead of geom_line I did geom_smooth, and you're right, that's much better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In ggplot2, the function geom_line can only connect observations in order of the variable on the x axis. In order to visualize the trend without limiting your lines to the values of observations (in your words, "smooth the lines"), geom_smooth is a better suited function.

So the corrected code would be:

```
ggplot() +
geom_smooth(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=df_Sweden$CENTAXINCOMESH, 
color="Income Taxes"), group=1) +
geom_smooth(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=df_Sweden$CENTAXPROPERTYSH, 
color="Property Taxes"), group=1) +
geom_smooth(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=df_Sweden$CENTAXCUSTOMSSH, 
color="Customs and International Trade"), group=1) +
geom_smooth(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=df_Sweden$CENTAXEXCISESH, 
color="Excise Taxes"), group=1) +
geom_smooth(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=df_Sweden$CENTAXCONSSH, 
color="Consumption Taxes"), group=1) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100),
                 labels=scales::label_percent(scale=1),
                 expand = expansion(0,0)) +
scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 30,
 limits = c(1890,2012), expand = c(0, 0)) + #yes shorted timeframe
scale_color_manual(values=c("Income Taxes" = "#991f00", "Property Taxes" = 
"#ff3300", "Customs and International Trade" = "#00ffff", "Excise Taxes" = 
"#0099ff", "Consumption Taxes" = "#0000cc")) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1)) +
xlab("Year") +
ylab("% of Government Revenue") +
labs(color="Tax Type") +
theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

Comment: even better if you would not use `$` within the calls to aes, and you might want to make the data frame long so you can use just one call to geom_smooth instead. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph