# R inconsistency: why add=T sometimes works and sometimes not in the plot() function?

Tags: r, plot, addition

Why is R inconsistent with the `add` parameter in the `plot()` function?
It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't!
In this example, it takes the parameter `add=TRUE` with no problem:

```
plot(0:10, 0:10*3)
plot(identity, add=TRUE, xlim=c(0,10))
plot(function (x) { sin(x)*10 }, add=TRUE, xlim=c(0,10))
```

But when I issue

```
plot(c(2, 3, 4), c(20,10,15), add=TRUE, pch="A")
```

It doesn't work!! It says that "add" is not a graphical parameter.

Please do not write that I should use `points()` instead. I know I can use it. 
I want to understand the strange behaviour of R - why does it sometimes work and sometimes not?

Comment: Can you please tell us the class of your object `identity`?

Comment: PS.  Note that using `T` as a shortcut for `TRUE` can get you into trouble.  Since `TRUE` is a reserved word, it will always be `TRUE`.  But you can redefine `T <- FALSE`, or `T <- 0` which can lead to all kinds of unexpected behaviour.

Comment: identity() is a standard function from package base (see ?identity). Thank you Andrie for comment on T and TRUE!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is admittedly annoying and inconsistent, but it's explicable.

`identity` is an object of a class — `function` — that has a `plot` method (`plot.function`) with an `add` argument, while the default `plot` method does **not** have an `add` argument.

In general, when trying to plot object `bar`, you should try `class(bar)`; if it is of class `foo` then try `methods(class="foo")` to see that it has a plot method, or `methods("plot")` to see that `plot.foo` exists.  Try `?plot.foo` (or `help("plot.foo")` to see help, or `plot.foo` to see the function itself. (If the method is a private function in the package `mypkg` you may need `mypkg:::plot_foo` or or `getAnywhere(plot.foo)`  to find it.)

Comment: Thank you Ben! Now it is clear!! Yes, ?plot.function redirects me to curve() and that explains it. But methods("plot") neither shows the plot.function nor curve. Also, the methods(class="function") doesn't give any answer about plot method...

Comment: You're right, they don't work. I think they should, though. I have sent a query to the r developers' list.

Comment: @Tomas: this may or may not be a comfort to you, but they do now work in the 'development' version of R.  This was a recent change ...

Comment: you should ask a new question.  My comment was not about `add` but about the use of `methods("plot")` and `methods(class="function")` (which do work).

Comment: a gotcha: `plot( acf( x, plot=FALSE ))` NOT `plot( acf(x) )`

Comment: my head just exploded!! hopefully I can figure this out later

Answer (score 31):

This is because when you call `plot(0:10, 0:10*3)` or `plot(c(2, 3, 4), c(20,10,15))`, you are indirectly calling `plot.default()`, which in turn calls `plot.xy()`, whereas the other two calls you mention are running `plot.function()`. `add` is an argument for `plot.function()`, but not for `plot.xy()`.

You can get around this inconsistency by setting `par(new = TRUE)`, but then you need to make sure that you don't add fresh axis labels or redraw the axes. **EDIT:** As pointed out in the comment, you have to make sure that the range is the same as the previous plot. e.g.:

```
plot(0:10, 0:10*3)
plot(identity, add=T, xlim=c(0,10))
plot(function (x) { sin(x)*10 }, add=T, xlim=c(0,10))
par(new = TRUE)
plot(c(2, 3, 4), c(20,10,15), pch="A",
     axes = FALSE, ## don't redraw the axes 
     xlab = '', ylab = '', ## no fresh axis labels
     xlim = c(0,10), ylim = c(0,30)) ## keep the same limits as before
```

As Ben Bolker mentions, `methods('plot')` will show you what methods can be called when running `plot()` - the different methods have different arguments, which are listed when you call `args(plot.foo)` or in the help page `?plot.foo`

Comment: Thank you nullglob for explanation too! It's clear now. But your example isn't very clean though :-) It doesn't work because the scale is different so the A letters are plotted at wrong positions :-) This is low level trick and I guess shouldn't be used, but thanks - maybe I use it one day :-)

Comment: You are correct - I forgot to preserve the range. This is something that you need to take care of when using `par(new = TRUE)`. I've now fixed it in the example.

Comment: It's not plot.xy() which is called (directly), but rather plot.default(), the S3 default method for plot().    {plot.xy() is not something a user should use typically, and it is *not* a plot() method even though its name may suggest so... mainly it's name is from the very old history of S, the precursor of R}