# R plot overlay barplot with plot type "p" (confused with factors)

Tags: r, plot

I'm new to R. Previously, I've been able to overlay 2 separate plots that were of the same kind, p1 and p2, using `plot (p1)`; `plot (p2, add=T)`.

I'm struggling with the definition of factors when overlaying a barplot with a point plot showing all individual points.

I can individually plot the barplot as I want it. The point plot looks like I want it, but I realize I'm using an incorrect definition of phase as numerical to force R plot to display each value, rather than default to a boxplot (like when I use `plot(my.df$cond, my.df$val)`.

Any tips on defining my variable types correctly or whether I'm using the correct barplot and plot functions, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

```
shpad <- c(1,2,5,6,1,2,5,6,1,2,5,6,1,2,5,6)
my.df <- data.frame(val=c(0.0738,0.0518,0.002,0.0397,0.1452,0.1152,0.1774,0.0658,0.0218,0.0497,-0.0296,0.0653,0.0848,0.1296,0.1416,0.0923,
    phase=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
    sub=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
    cond=c("NsNm", "NsNm", "NsNm", "NsNm", "NsLm", "NsLm", "NsLm", "NsLm", "LsNm", "LsNm", "LsNm", "LsNm", "LsLm", "LsLm", "LsLm", "LsLm"))
avg <-tapply(my.df$val, my.df$phase, mean)
barplot(avg, border=NA, names.arg=c("NsNm", "NsLm", "LsNm", "LsLm"),col=c("blue","darkblue","red", "darkred"),ylab = "score",ylim=c(-0.03,0.25))
plot(my.df$phase, my.df$val, type="p", ylim=c(-0.03,0.25), ylab = "score",  pch=shpad)
```

tl;dr: problem is that if instead of the last line, I have `plot(my.df$phase, my.df$val, type="p", ylim=c(-0.03,0.25), ylab = "score",  pch=shpad, add=T)`, the formats are incongruent.

Comment: So, is your main problem the fact that R won't let you add the overlay the second plot on the first because of errors begin issued about `add=T`? If so, your problem is [due to different classes of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789055/r-inconsistency-why-add-t-sometimes-works-and-sometimes-not-in-the-plot-funct). You may want to use `points` if dealing with plots of different types. I'm also not sure why you chose a bar plot to represent the averages. It doesn't seem to be the best choice of plot, since you want to plot points next.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I understand that it's an unconventional approach to overlay individual points over a barplot (It is because the means relative to zero are interpretable so barplots are standard in plotting these data in my field of research; I need error bars but these are misleading due to the small sample size; and don't emphasize my within-subject design).

Comment: @abcde13 Thank you for suggesting the points function. However, on a barplot, I have categories on the x-axis and can't seem to define the (x,y) location of the points. Any other suggestions of how to create a barplot that would be in x, y coordinates?

Comment: @abcde13 Thank you! R let me plot points over a barplot, I just need to figure out the correspondence on the x axis. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad you found my comments useful. You may want to check out the answer I've written below. It gives a neater solution using ggplot2, especially if you are still having problems with the correspondence on the x-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so, I've tried for a bit to accomplish what you wanted, but the best I could do with the base plotting system is this:[image]

Which is accomplished purely by your lines of code above except for the last line, which I replaced with

```
points(my.df$phase,my.df$val,type="p",pch=shpad)
```

---

However, I think you can do much better, if you want to keep the same kind of plot, using the `ggplot2` library. Using this code:

```
library('ggplot2')

new.df <- data.frame(avg,phase=levels(factor(phase)))
ggplot(new.df) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(x=levels(phase),y=avg, fill=c("NsNm","NsLm","LsNm","LsLm")))+ 
    geom_point(aes(x=my.df$phase,y=my.df$val,shape=factor(shpad))) + 
    scale_x_discrete(name="Type",labels=c("NsNm","NsLm","LsNm","LsLm")) +
    ylab("Score")
```

you can make this chart:
[image]

I didn't adjust the coloring and the point types and the legend titles (not sure how important they are, but those can be fiddled with). However, you can see this probably produces the result you were aiming for.