# using R - how to integrate 2 bubble graphs in one graph

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization

I'm testing the R project with a bubble graph. For this, I have the following csv file:

[download result.csv file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4510097/stackoverflow/result.csv)

I did this:

```
> mydata<-read.csv("~/Desktop/result.csv", header=TRUE)
> mydata

  month     sale    comm maxcomm savings
  1 23415960  706164  998457  292293
  2 21303842  870591  928084   57493
  3 22128502  644698  897262  252564
  4 23872123  800024 1047968  247944
  5 25880653  900984 1006359  105375
  6 26359929 1186594 1601646  415052
```

for the command below, I get the red bubble

> symbols(mydata$sale, mydata$comm, circles=mydata$savings, bg="red")

and for the command below, I get the blue bubble

> symbols(mydata$sale, mydata$comm, circles=mydata$maxcomm, bg="blue")

My goal is to integrate them both together (in one graph) so the red will be **on top** of the blue. (If there's any possibility to have the blue transparent - even better!)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this, but staying within the base graphics package you can use the `par()` command and add plots on top of each other. Also, to control transparency, you can convert your colors to hexadecimal values (red is #FF0000, blue is #0000FF) and add two digits at the end represending the alpha transparency layer

```
symbols(mydata$sale, mydata$comm, circles=mydata$savings, bg="#FF0000")
par(new=TRUE)
symbols(mydata$sale, mydata$comm, circles=mydata$maxcomm, bg="#0000FF50")
```

This sets the transparency of the second symbol chart to 50% 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH8cM.png)

Also see this related question for more detail: [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-2-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r)

Comment: To adding transparency: `adjustcolor("blue", 0.5)`.

Answer (score 4):

Set `add=TRUE`:

```
symbols(mydata$sale, mydata$comm, circles=mydata$maxcomm, bg="blue")
symbols(mydata$sale, mydata$comm, circles=mydata$savings, bg="red", add=TRUE)
```

Take a look at `rgb()` or the `ggplot` function for transparent colors (referred to by `alpha`.