# Plot two graphs in the same plot

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

[The solution with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14553602/) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-2-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r) worked really well for my data. However, I am trying to add a legend and everything that I tried does not work...

For example, in the ggplot example in the above question, how I can add a legend to show that the red curve is related to "Ocean" and the green curve is related to "Soil"? Yes, I want to add text that I will define and it is not related to any other variable in my data.frame.

The example below is some of my own data...

```
Rate     Probability      Stats
1.0e-04    1e-04          891.15 
1.0e-05    1e-04          690
...
```

etc (it's about 400 rows). And I have two data frames similar to the above one.
So My code is

```
g <- ggplot(Master1MY, aes(Probability))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(y=Master1MY$Stats), colour="red", size=1)
g <- g + geom_point(aes(y=Transposon1MY$Stats), colour="blue", size=1)
g + labs(title= "10,000bp and 1MY", x = "Probability", y = "Stats")
```

The plot looks like[image: this]

I just want a red and blue legend saying "Master" and "Transposon"

Thanks!

Comment: Ignore the accepted answer the linked question, look at the second and third instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `ggplot` it is generally most convenient to keep the data in a 'long' format. Here I use the function `melt` from the `reshape2` package to convert your data from wide to long format. Depending how you specify different `aes`thetics (size, shape, colour et c), corresponding legends will appear.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# data from the example you were referring to, in a 'wide' format.
x  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
ocean <- pnorm(x)
soil <- pnorm(x, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(x, ocean, soil)

# melt the data to a long format
df2 <- melt(data = df, id.vars = "x")

# plot, using the aesthetics argument 'colour'
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

**Edit, set name and labels of legend**

```
# Manually set name of the colour scale and labels for the different colours
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = value, colour = variable)) +
 geom_line() +
 scale_colour_discrete(name = "Type of sample", labels = c("Sea water", "Soil"))
```

**Edit2, following new sample data**
Convert your data, *assuming* its organization from your update, to a long format. Again, I believe you make your `ggplot` life easier if you keep your data in a long format. I relate every step with the simple example data which I used in my first answer. Please note that there are many alternative ways to rearrange your data. This is one way, based on the small (non-reproducible) parts of your data you provided in the update.

```
# x  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
# Master1MY$Probability
Probability <- 1:100

# ocean <- pnorm(x)
# Master1MY$Stats
Master1MY <- rnorm(100, mean = 600, sd = 20)

# soil <- pnorm(x,1,1)
# Transposon1MY$Stats
Transposon1MY <- rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 10)

# df <- data.frame(x, ocean, soil)
df <- data.frame(Probability, Master1MY, Transposon1MY)

# df2 <- melt(df, id.var = "x")
df2 <- melt(df, id.var = "Probability")

# default
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Probability, y = value, col = variable)) +
  geom_point()

# change legend name and labels, see previous edit using 'scale_colour_discrete'

# set manual colours scale using 'scale_colour_manual'.

ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Probability, y = value, col = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue"), name = "Type of sample", labels = c("Master", "Transposon"))
```

[image]

Comment: It might be worth adding this example to the ggplot answer in the question linked above as well. For an answer with 12 upvotes, it's not really a great example of `ggplot` code.

Comment: Good point. @Fabs was a bit unfortunate to stumble over a wide format example.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think this example will work for me now... (or maybe I didn't understand the example, and sorry about that)... I will edit my question and show part of my example... maybe there is a simple way of doing what I want to do .... thanks again!

Comment: Again, I believe you make your `ggplot` life much easier if you keep your data in a data frame in a long format. Try to see how your different 'real' variables in your update correspond to the variables in the test data you referred to, and work your way to a (one) long data frame. I have added a small example.

Comment: Hi Thanks! Now I understood and I could reproduce using my data. Thanks a lot again!