# How to plot three vectors/line charts on one figure?

Tags: r

> How to draw one line chart with 3 lines in R?

```
 min<-c(1,1,4,5)
 max<-c(8,9,8,10)
 d<-c(-2,3,4,3)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot two graphs in same plot in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `matplot` after `cbind`ing the `vector`s to create a `matrix`

```
matplot(cbind(min, max, d), type='l')
```

To change the 'x axis' labels, we can plot with `xaxt=n` and change the `labels` with `axis`

```
matplot(cbind(min, max, d), type='l', xaxt='n', col=2:4)
axis(1, at=1:4, labels=letters[1:4])
legend('topright', legend=c('min', 'max', 'd'), col=2:4, pch=1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add labels on x axis like "a","b","c","d"?

Comment: @zone1 Your example is numeric data.  So, I don't know where you want to label

Comment: @zone1 Perhaps `matplot(cbind(min, max, d), type='l', xaxt='n');
 axis(1, at=1:4, labels=letters[1:4])`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to complete @akrun's very good answer, and based on [this page](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/directlabels-adding-direct-labels-to-ggplot2-and-lattice-plots/):

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(directlabels)

min <- c( 1, 1, 4, 5)
max <- c( 8, 9, 8, 10)
d   <- c(-2, 3, 4, 3)

df <- data.frame(min=min, max=max, d=d, x=1:4)
df.m <- melt(df,id.vars="x")

p <- ggplot(df.m, aes(x=x, y=value, color=variable)) + geom_line()

direct.label(p)
```

[image: the result]

Comment: Good to know about the directlabels