# How to plot 2 time series on one chart with 2 axes in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I looked at [Plot two graphs in same plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r) but did not figure it out.

```
trend.ts = ts(c(100,101,102))
plot(trend.ts)
season.ts = ts(c(3,4,5))
lines(season.ts)
```

Apparently `lines` does not draw the season.ts because it is outside of the left y axis.

How to draw it on the same graph on its own right y axis?

Is there some introductory documentation that shows this?

Comment: Yes, I did. Are you suggesting that one of the links that you found by Googling has a clear answer?

Comment: @BSeven He even linked it for you

Comment: Most certainly, yes. Try `par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.3) ; plot(trend.ts) ; par(new = TRUE) ; plot(1:3, season.ts, type = "l", axes = FALSE, bty = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "") ; axis(side=4, at = pretty(range(season.ts))) ; mtext("season.ts", side=4, line=3)` Though you won't notice it because both of your series are identical while scaled. So maybe try this for `season.ts = ts(c(5,4,3))`. Anyway, I'm hammering this unless someone has any objections.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - Thanks, your example worked. Why do you set these params `1:3, season.ts, type = "l", axes = FALSE, bty = "n", xlab = "", ylab = ""`?

Comment: That will require a lot of explanations. Please read `?par` and `?xy.coords` especially after the "*If y is NULL and x is a*" part.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - OK, thanks for the info.