# How to include a candle stick plot and a line chart in the same chart in R

Tags: r, linechart, candlestick-chart

I have some stock prices `High`, `Low`, `Open`, `Close`. I would like to use R to draw a candle stick chart, then I have another customer indicator (a type of moving average) that I have developed and I would like to plot that as a line chart over the candle sticks.

Also I would like to be able to specify he colour of the line chart that I add to the candlestick chart.

```
miniChart <- as.xts(miniSubset,order.by=miniDF$GMT.x..i..)
#Create quantmod chart
candleChart(miniChart)
```

Please could someone tell me how I would add a line chart on the candlechart above?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `candleChart` from the [quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com/examples/charting/) package or `gvisCandlestickChart` from [googleVis](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/googleVis/html/gvisCandlestickChart.html). Quantmod was specifically designed to work with financial data so I'd suggest you start with it.

Once you're happy with the candle stick chart, then  you can add an overlying line chart.

Comment: lol that is my question. What is the code to write the chart and the overlying line chart?

Comment: like how do you add an overlying line chart onto a quantmod candlestick chart

Comment: read your question again. you didn't mention any packages used or haven't shared any code used. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please check my question, I have edited it. If you know how to add a line to the candlstick chart, please write the code for this.