# Plot two barplot in same plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm a beginner in R, so maybe it sounds simple but I'm looking to stack two 
`bar plot`.
For example, for the city BIRR, I have two graphs: one with the precipitations, the other with the temperatures.
What I am trying to do is that for each month 04/2004, I would like to have the barplot stacks temperatures and the barplot stacks precipitation.

I put you my dataset below:

```
#TEMP_BIR 
"SOUNAME" "year_month" "temperature_type" "temperature_value"    
"1" "BIRR" "2004-04" "VERY_COLD" 0    
"2" "BIRR" "2004-05" "VERY_COLD" 0    
"3" "BIRR" "2004-06" "VERY_COLD" 0    
"4" "BIRR" "2004-07" "VERY_COLD" 0    
"5" "BIRR" "2004-04" "MEDIUM" 28    
"6" "BIRR" "2004-05" "MEDIUM" 29    
"7" "BIRR" "2004-06" "MEDIUM" 19    
"8" "BIRR" "2004-07" "MEDIUM" 25    
"9" "BIRR" "2004-04" "HOT" 0    
"10" "BIRR" "2004-05" "HOT" 2    
"11" "BIRR" "2004-06" "HOT" 11    
"12" "BIRR" "2004-07" "HOT" 6    
"13" "BIRR" "2004-04" "COLD" 2    
"14" "BIRR" "2004-05" "COLD" 0    
"15" "BIRR" "2004-06" "COLD" 0    
"16" "BIRR" "2004-07" "COLD" 0  

# Temp_prec_birr 
"SOUNAME" "year_month" "precipitation_type" "precipitation_value"    
"BIRR" "2004-04" "NONE" "11"    
"BIRR" "2004-05" "NONE" "20"    
"BIRR" "2004-06" "NONE" "11"    
"BIRR" "2004-07" "NONE" "10"    
"BIRR" "2004-04" "HEAVY" "2"    
"BIRR" "2004-05" "HEAVY" "1"    
"BIRR" "2004-06" "HEAVY" "1"    
"BIRR" "2004-07" "HEAVY" "1"    
"BIRR" "2004-04" "LIGHT" "15"    
"BIRR" "2004-05" "LIGHT" "7"    
"BIRR" "2004-06" "LIGHT" "16"    
"BIRR" "2004-07" "LIGHT" "18"    
"BIRR" "2004-04" "MEDIUM" "2"    
"BIRR" "2004-05" "MEDIUM" "3"    
"BIRR" "2004-06" "MEDIUM" "2"    
"BIRR" "2004-07" "MEDIUM" "2"


#I put you my code below:

ggplot(data = TEMP_PREC_BIRR, aes(x = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$year_month, 
                                  y = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$precipitation_value, 
                                  fill = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$precipitation_type)) + 
  geom_bar(aes (width = .2), stat = "identity") + 
  xlab("date") + ylab ("Number of days of precipitation") + 
  ggtitle("Precipitation per month - BIRR") + labs(fill = "Frequency")

ggplot(data = TEMP_BIRR, aes(x = TEMP_BIRR$year_month, 
                             y = TEMP_BIRR$temperature_value, 
                             fill = TEMP_BIRR$temperature_type)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(width = .2), stat = "identity") + 
    xlab("date") + ylab("Number of days of temperature") + 
  ggtitle("Temperature per month - BIRR") + labs(fill = "Frequency")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot two graphs in same plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library called `gridExtra` to do that. It has a function `grid.arrange()` that does just that. Further, you can specify the arrangements by specifying the number of rows or number of column of the plot by passing it to `nrow` or `ncol`.

example: If you want to arrange 6 plots into 3X2 then use

```
grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,plot3,plot4,plot5,plot6,nrow=2)
```

To answer your problem look at the code and output below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
Data=iris
a=ggplot(Data,aes(x=Data$Sepal.Length,Data$Petal.Length,color=Data$Species))+
  geom_point()+theme(panel.background = element_blank())+
  labs(x="Sepal Length",y="Petal Length",color="Species")
b=ggplot(Data,aes(x=Data$Sepal.Width,Data$Petal.Width,color=Data$Species))+
  geom_point()+theme(panel.background = element_blank())+
  labs(x="Sepal Width",y="Petal Width",color="Species")
grid.arrange(a,b)
```

[image: The output of the Image is Here]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I had already done that, but the graphics are one below the other, I would like to have one over the other.

Comment: @ElodieP., I think you just need to switch the order in your function, so is `grid.arrange(b, a)` instead of `grid.arrange(a,b)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr::bindrows()` to combine the two sets, and then use `tidyr::gather()` to put your temperature and precipitation values in one column where `key = precipitation_or_temp` and `value = value`.  You can then use one `ggplot` object with a `facet_wrap` on the precipitation_or_temp variable to get your two plots.

Check out this link for info on gather: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html
And check out this link for more info on facets: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html

Really do check out the *R for Data Science* book.  It's really easy to follow and will actually help with these answers.  Here's how you make the graph with some sample data.  Actually arranging the data into the appropriate format is a task I'll leave for you.

```
library(tidyverse)  
data <- 
  tibble(
    month = as_factor(c("January", "January", "February", "February")),
    value_type = c("temperature", "precipitation", "temperature", "precipitation"),
    value = c(30, 25, 40, 25))

ggplot(data) +
  geom_col(aes(x = month, y = value) +
  facet_wrap(~value-type)
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin,
Thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately I did not understand very well ...
Is it possible to show me an example with the data set please?
Thank you in advance,
Elodie

Comment: @ElodieP.  I added some sample code for how to use `facet_wrap()` in ggplot, but you'll have to arrange the data in the format I used.  Really do read the info in the links I posted, they are invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you want to plot, But you need to arrange your data so much using `dplyr` and/or `melt` it to get desired output. It's a tedious process.

Although I found the problem in your code. If you are trying to fix your code you have to use only one `ggplot()` function to plot in the same region. If you create two `ggplot()` functions your output will be plotted in another plane.

Here's the correct way to use your version of the code with the output:

```
ggplot(data = TEMP_PREC_BIRR, aes(x = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$year_month, 
                                  y = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$precipitation_value, 
                                  fill = TEMP_PREC_BIRR$precipitation_type,width=0.2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = position_nudge(x=-0.2)) + 
  xlab("date") + ylab ("Number of days of precipitation") + 
  ggtitle("Precipitation per month - BIRR") + labs(fill = "Frequency")+
  geom_bar(data=TEMP_BIRR,aes(x=TEMP_BIRR$year_month, 
                                 y=TEMP_BIRR$temperature_value, 
                                 fill=TEMP_BIRR$temperature_type), stat = "identity",position = position_nudge(x=0.2)) + 
  xlab("date") + ylab("Number of days of temperature") + 
  ggtitle("Temperature per month - BIRR") + labs(fill = "Frequency")
```

[image: Output Plot]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !! I'm really happy, thank you again for your help.

However, I have a question. How come bars do not go up to 30 - 31? Because it's the number of days per month, so normally the sum per month is 30 or 31. Is it understandable?