# error in par, object true not found

Tags: r

```
i am a starter in R, probably this is a very foolish question but please help.
x =c(rnorm(100))
y = c(rnorm(100)) ## for the graph
plot(x,col = "blue")
par(new=True) ## to superimpose the new graph on the previous
plot(y,col = "red")
why does this give an error as
```

> Error in par(new = True) : object 'True' not found

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *add* a plot on top of an existing plot, then use the [`lines`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/lines.html) function:

```
x <- c(rnorm(100))
y <- c(rnorm(100))
plot(x, col="blue")
lines(y, col = "red")
```

Answer (score 0):

"type true in all CAPS TRUE"
par(new=True) ## wrong
par(new=TRUE) ## Correct

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things . please elaborate your answer