# How to plot graphic from several data.frame

Tags: r, plot

Supose I have this tree dataframes, where the first row represents a place and first colum represents a day.

```
z<-c("a", 2, 3)
x<-c("b",2,3)
y<-c("c",4,5)


w<-c("a",5,3)
v<-c("b",6,5)
r<-c("c",2,1)

q<-c("a",2,5)
p<-c("b",4,5)
t<-c("c",2,1)

g<-c(NA,1,2)

df1<-data.frame(g, z,x,y)
df2<-data.frame(g, w,v,r)
df3<-data.frame(g, q,p,t)
```

I want to plot several graphics containing the information of the 3 dataframes.
I want to represent the values of df1, df2 and df3, in the graphic for each day and place. So for example, I want to plot for day 1, df1, df2, df3, and so on. An the same for place a, i want to plot df1, df2, df3.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far and where you failed.

Comment: I don't know any function for ploting diferent dataframes in the same plot..

Comment: What are the "days" and "places" supposed to be in this case? And this sample data doesn't make much sense. You can't have character values and numeric values in the same vector. Everything will just be coerced into a character. Maybe you can draw a sketch of the desired output for this sample data. Most likely things will be easier if you just merge the three data.frames before plotting.

Comment: Do you want 3 plots size by side in the same plot? Do you want the lines to be layered on a single plot? This probably has your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot two graphs in same plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r)

Comment: I don't think it is duplicated, because I need to plot two graphics (number of days, taht in reality are 76), with the lines of the 3 dataframes, and later I want to plot the places (which are 35). @divibisan

Comment: @MrFlick days are represented by 1,2 and places by a,b,c. This is dummy data to be easier. the numbers in the middle are what's going to be in my graphic.

Comment: If you were willing to use `ggplot()` instead of `plot()`, it is fairly easy: `ggplot() + geom_line(data = df1 ...) + geom_line(data = df2 ...) + geom_line(data = df3 ...)`. You simply specify that each `geom_line` uses a different data frame, and they are all plotted together.

Comment: All plotting functions in R, either in base or in higher level packages can plot data from arbitrary sources, as they all accept passing references to vectors from different data frames or matrices. The tricky part is how to map the different vectors (data series) to different plot properties... You need to be more specific about what you want plotted and how, where the data comes from is secondary.

Comment: @gorgonzola in this case I want 5 plots: 
one that gives me day 1 with three lines corresponding to df1, df2, df3 with the values of a,b,c in their x axis.
the same for day 2
then, I need on for a, with 3 lines df1, df2, df3, that gives me the value in day 1 and 2;
another plot for b and c.

Answer (score 0):

See `?par` and the `mfrow` argument. You can set the value for `mfrow` to define how many rows and columns of plots you want in a grid.

https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html