# how to plot two graphs in the same panel (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, curve-fitting

I just need to put two different curves (one GLM segmented regression and a normal GLM of the same data) into a single panel (one graph, not different facets). I have been able only to place the two graphs next to each other (below), but what I need is to include the blue curve into the other graph. Any thoughts on how to get around this issue? Hopefully, this might be a very straightforward question for someone with experience in ggplot2.

[image: Two graphs side by side]

The closest I got to merge these two curves was by converting some data into a data.frame as recommended in some post (using library(reshape2, [Plot two graphs in same plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r)), and I managed to get this (below). But it has been difficult to plot the Conf. Intervals for the GLM  (green line here) and the points, so I wonder if there is an easier path to join the above curves (I scaled y axis).

I have also tried some other suggestions found online such as just adding the two graphs using add= TRUE and so on. Thanks in advance.

[image: Both lines in the same plot, but no confidence intervals]

Further information:
Thanks much for responding. The data consist of a gradient of oil palm proportion (x.oilpalm) in a landscape (the explanatory variable) and the response is species richness (spp.obs_NP).

```
head(dati)
```

x  y
1 50.155835  8
2 34.648817 10
3 80.927821 11
4 53.352809  8
5  1.303226 10
6 31.818881  9

## So for the GLM plot (left-hand side). I used this code:

```
p1 <- ggplot(newdata, aes(x=x.oilpalm, y=fit)) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = .25) +   
geom_line(size = 1) +
geom_point(data = vars, aes(y = spp.obs_NP, x = x.oilpalm)) +
labs(x = "Percentage of oil palm coverage", y = "Mammalian species richness")  
+
theme_bw()    
print(p1)

p2 <- p1 + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", size = 12),
             axis.text.y = element_text(color="black", size = 12),
             axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
             axis.title.x = element_text(size =13))
p2
```

### for figure in the right side (segmented GLM regression)

```
p6 <- ggplot(dati, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = dat22, color = 'blue') +
  ylab("Mammalian species richness") +
  xlab("Percentage of oil palm coverage")+theme_bw() 

p7 <- p6 + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", size = 12),
             axis.text.y = element_text(color="black", size = 12),
             axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
             axis.title.x = element_text(size =13))
p7
```

### putting together the two graph side by side

## first I rescale p7 so the Y axis is also 16 maximum

```
  p8a <- ggplot(dati, aes(x = x, y = y, ymax= y+ 3.5)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = dat22, color = 'blue',linetype ="dashed", lwd = 1) +
  ylab("Mammalian species richness") +
  xlab("Percentage of oil palm coverage")+theme_bw() 
  p9a <- p8a + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", size = 12),
               axis.text.y = element_text(color="black", size = 12),
               axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
               axis.title.x = element_text(size =13))
  p9a
```

## then I just used gridExtra to put the two graphs together

```
library(gridExtra)
 aa <- grid.arrange( p2,  p9a, ncol=2)
 p22 <- aa + scale_y_continuous()
```

*please don't worry about the legends, I can make it tidier if I was going to use this style. But I need just one figure. This is, overlapping that blue curve (right) on the left panel.

## SOLUTION (see comments)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3PXp.png)
[image]

Comment: sorry I just noted, I cannot post figures, hope I made myself clear. I just need to put two fitted curves into a single figure. Thanks

Comment: Please create some simple example data as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and show the code you're using to achieve your current results (I think particularly the first example image).

Comment: As it is, this looks like an easy task. But if you don't post any data it will be nearly impossible to help.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you. I have included more information.

Comment: You're already feeding different data to each `geom_line()`. Just put everything together using the element arithmetic: `ggplot(...) + geom_point() + geom_line( data = vars, aes(y = spp.obs_NP, x = x.oilpalm) ) + geom_line( data = dat22, aes(x = x, y = y) ) + ...`

Comment: Hi @ArtemSokolov, it worked really well. Thanks much. (I'll try to paste the result above in the question if it allow me)