# Is there any way to plot several categorical Y variables in the same graph that has the same categorical X variable?

Tags: r, plot, categorical-data

In my dataset, the x-variable is a categorical variable called "Agency" which has 3 variables. I am trying to plot multiple Y variables called "Limitation 1, Limitation 2,...Limitation7" to make a single graph that contains all the y variables and the x variable at the bottom. Below is the sample code I used to get the individual bar graphs, but is there a code that enables me to merge the results from all the 7 categorical Y variables into one layout?

This is currently the code I am using to get individual bar graphs and I did this for all the limitations

```
counts7 <- table(dataset$Limitation1, dataset$Agency)

barplot(counts7,main="Limitation1 and Agency",                                                                                  
    xlab="HTA Agency", col=c("darkgrey","black")                                
    legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot two graphs in same plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r)

Comment: It's hard to say without sample data or being able to see your output. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that's easier for folks to help with

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have your data, and maybe a more detailed explanation of what you want, but here is a go using a slightly modified version of the inbuilt `airquality` data set. Using `melt()` from `reshape2` to convert from wide to long representation (makes tabulation much easier), and `barchart()` from `lattice` to make the multi-way plot.

```
library(lattice)
library(reshape2)

airq <- airquality[, -6]
airq[,1:4] <- lapply(airq[,1:4], 
  function(x) cut(x, quantile(x, na.rm=TRUE), labels=1:4))

airq.tab <- table(melt(airq, id.vars="Month"))

barchart(airq.tab, stack=FALSE, layout=c(1, 4), horizontal=FALSE, xlab="Month")
```

[image]