# Fitting two coefplot in one graph using par(mfrow()) method

Tags: r, multirow, coefplot

I'm trying to arrange two `coefplot` objects into one graph via the `par(mfrow(,))` method, but it didn't work out. What did I do wrong? Or is that `coefplot` just doesn't work this way? What will be alternative method?
I've referenced this [earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r), but I tend to think that mine is a quite different issue.

```css
# load the data
dat <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/88h7hmiroalx3de/act.rds?dl=1"))


#fit two models
library(lmer4)

act1.fit <- glmer(act1 ~ os + education + marital + nat6 + nat5 + nat4 + nat3 + nat2 + nat1 + 
    (1 | region_id), data = action, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
    nAGQ = 10)
    
action2.fit <- glmer(act2 ~ os + education + marital + nat6 + nat5 + nat4 + nat3 + nat2 + nat1 + 
    (1 | region_id), data = action, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
    nAGQ = 10)
    

# plot the two model individually
library(coefplot)

# construct coefplot objects

coefplot:::buildModelCI(action1.fit)
         
coefplot:::buildModelCI(action2.fit)
coefplot(action2.fit, coefficients=c("nat1", "nat2", "nat3", "nat4", "nat5", "nat6"), 
         intercept = FALSE, color = "brown3")
         
# arrange two plots in one graph
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
coefplot(action1.fit, coefficients=c("nat1", "nat2", "nat3", "nat4", "nat5", "nat6"), 
         intercept = FALSE, color = "brown3")
         
coefplot(action2.fit, coefficients=c("nat1", "nat2", "nat3", "nat4", "nat5", "nat6"), 
         intercept = FALSE, color = "brown3")         

# didn't work ???
```

Comment: I think `coefplot` is `ggplot2` based ; if so you can combine with `gridExtra::grid.arrange`

Comment: Many thanks! Would you put this as formal reply so I can mark it as solved?