# Add quadratic line in R plot

Tags: r, time-series, quadratic, trend

I drew phillips curve for 2007-2020 and I want to add quadratic trend.
My phillips curve form is as follows:

```
plot(u, p, xlab="u", ylab="p")
```

Comment: Do you have a specific programming language in mind? If so, please add this tag to your question. Right now there are missing some information.

Comment: my series; p <- ts(rsvar$inflation, start = c(2007,1), frequency = 4)
u <- ts(rsvar$unemployment, start = c(2007,1), frequency = 4) and ı want to curve trend not linear trend

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65945010/edit) your post. Don't post your code as a comment. And which programming language do you use?

Comment: ım using R programming language

Comment: Maybe this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r) will help you.